# is it ok to use parchment paper when baking cream puffs

Tags: baking

Is it better to use parchment paper when baking cream puffs so that the middle does not end up being wet and soggy?

Answer (score 3):

Yes to your title.

No to the question body.

I always use parchment when baking cream puffs. It is just to make the cream puffs not stick to the pan and cleanup easier.

It doesn't insulate enough to affect baking temperature and has no effect on the cream puffs being wet and soggy or not.

Answer (score 0):

It's totally fine to bake on parchment, but it will not help the soggy issue.

-you may need to bake them longer, try a lower temp if the outside is over cooked but the inside is underdone.

-if they are good fresh out of the oven, but they become soggy later...remove from oven after baking. Poke a small hole and return to the oven off and with the door ajar. After they are cool, they should not get soggy. Fill and eat!!! :)

Comment: This is an example where mentioning your site isn't really appropriate. You're not using it to specifically address the question. If there are particular posts there that you think really add a lot (and the information is too much to summarize here) you could certainly link to them. But here, it's not helping you answer the question, so it's more in the category of unsolicited self-promotion.